# Creating asymmetric keys in SQL Server 2014 for unsafe assemblies

Tags: c#, sql-server, assemblies, sqlclr, encryption-asymmetric

I have 2 DLLs signed in Visual Studio (VS) 2015. A former employee created an asymmetric key and login and I ran one of the assemblies in `UNSAFE` mode correctly.

I get the following error with the second one:

> Msg 10327, Level 14, State 1, Line 27
>      CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'TableFile' failed because assembly 'TableFile' is not authorized for PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE.  The assembly is authorized when either of the following is true: the database owner (DBO) has UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission and the database has the TRUSTWORTHY database property on; or the assembly is signed with a certificate or an asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission.

I can't ask the former employee so how do I find out how to get this to run?  I tried this too:

```
USE master; 
GO  

CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY AProjectKey FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'E:\sqldlls\TableFile.dll' 
CREATE LOGIN AProjectLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY AProjectKey ;  
GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO AProjectLogin ;
GO
```

This gives the following errors:

> Msg 15396, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>    An asymmetric key with name 'AProjectKey' already exists or this asymmetric key already has been added to the database.
>
> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Cannot find the asymmetric key 'AProjectKey', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>
> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Cannot find the login 'AProjectLogin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

How do I get both these assemblies running in unsafe mode? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding those 3 error messages:

1. The first could be due to the Asymmetric Key already existing, but under a different name. Keys and Certificates need to be unique in terms of their public key, not just the name (though that obviously needs to be unique as well). Each Key and Certificate has a hash of the public key which is referred to as the "thumbprint". The thumbprints of existing Keys / Certificates are checked when creating a new one and will prevent the creation, even of a differently named Key / Certificate, if the thumbprint already exists. That is what the error message means by "or this asymmetric key already has been added to the database".

   OR:

   It could mean that a different Asymmetric Key (i.e. different "thumbprint") exists in `master`, but with the name `AProjectKey`
2. Because you couldn't create the same key under a different name, no Asymmetric Key exists with that new name, hence you can't create a Login from it (since, again, the `CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY` statement failed).
3. Because you couldn't create the Login, it doesn't exist to be granted any permissions.

Error # 2 helps narrow down the issue. If Error # 1 was caused by an existing Asymmetric Key having the same name but different "thumbprint", then you either would have been able to create the Login (if it did not already exist), or you would have gotten an error stating that the Login (i.e. "server principal") already exists. But the error is that an Asymmetric Key by that *name* cannot be found. This should mean that the Asymmetric Key itself does already exist, but under a different name. You can see what Asymmetric Keys have been created by executing the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.asymmetric_keys;
```

But that doesn't tell you which one came from that Assembly (or an Assembly signed with the same Strong Name Key used to sign this one). For that you need to know the "thumbprint", and for that you need to open a Command Prompt (preferably a "Developer Command Prompt" which Visual Studio sets up when installed, as it has the correct path set up upon opening it). Then, run the following:

```
CD /D E:\sqldlls\
sn -T TableFile.dll
```

You should see:

```
Public key token is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Copy and paste that XXXXX "token" (i.e. thumbprint) into the following query:

```sql
SELECT ak.[name], ak.[sid]
FROM   sys.asymmetric_keys ak
WHERE  ak.[thumbprint] = 0x{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}; -- remove the { and }
```

Assuming that you get a row returned, we need to see if the Login exists. Simply trying to create a Login from the Asymmetric Key won't get us the Login's name if it does exist since you can only have 1 Login created per Key / Certificate, and the error message only reports back the name you are trying to create as the one that already exists, even though it can be a different name for the same Key. So, take the SID from the returned row and paste it in the following query:

```sql
SELECT sp.*
FROM   sys.server_principals sp
WHERE  sp.[sid] = 0x{SID_from_sys_asymmetric_keys}; -- remove the { and }
```

If no row is returned then you should create a Login from that Asymmetric Key.

At this point a Login should exist, so grant it the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission.

Now try creating the Assembly again.

Comment: Totally fixed up my issue!

Comment: @cdub Awesome! Was the Login missing, or was it there and just needed the permission?

Comment: The login was there it just needed the permission.

Comment: @cdub Thanks for clarifying. I asked partially because it is possible the Login did have the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` permission, but doesn't allow for `UNSAFE` assemblies.